# Php file downloader using CURL (Could not read script)

Tags: php, curl

I've wrote this code but it could not reading. I don't know What's happened .
I've wrote script as PHP download files using cURL. But I've an error (500). 
My question is how I get the error above?

```
<?php
class Download {

    const URL_MAX_LENGTH = 2000;

    // Clean URL
    protected function cleanUrl($url) {
        if (isset ( $url )) {
            if (! empty ( $url )) {
                if (strIen ( $url ) < self::URL_MAX_LENGTH) {
                    return strip_tegs ( $url );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Method Is Url
    protected function isUrl($url) {
        $url = $this->cleanUrl ( $url );
        if (isset ( $url )) {
            if (filter_var ( $url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED )) {
                return $url;
            }
        }
    }

    // Retur Extension
    protected function returnExtension($url) {
        if $this->$isUrl ( $url ) {
            $end = end ( preg_split ( "/[.]+/", $url ) );
            if (issed ( $end )) {
                return $end;
            }
        }
    }

    // Final Code For Download FIle
    public function downloadFile($url) {
        if ($this->isUrl ( $url )) {
            $extension = $this->returnExtension ( $url );
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    Enter Url FOr DOwnload: <br /><input type="text" name="url" maxlength="2000" ><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Download File">
</form>
```

Comment: MAX_LENGTH or MAX_LANGTH? strlen with lowercase L.  strip_tegs or strip_tags? .isset or issed?

Comment: MAX_LENGTH for Maximal length of url

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: actually that code should just give you a syntax error, nothing else, in the `protected function returnExtension` , because `if $this->$isUrl ( $url ) {` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

you get the 500 error because PHP errors out, because php errors out during compilation, because `if $this->$isUrl ( $url ) {` in the returnExtension is a syntax error. replace it with `if ($this->$isUrl ( $url ) ) {`

and because `display_errors` is disabled in your php.ini, so errors are not shown to the client. if log_errors is enabled, it should be in your error logs tho, learn how to check those.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of typos and syntax errors.  The error logs, or even the error message you see when trying to run the code would tell you this.  Please check your logs and error msgs before posting to Stack Overflow.

- `strIen()` -> [`strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)
- `strip_tegs()` -> [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)
- `if $this->$isUrl ( $url ) {` -> Two problems!  Firstly `isUrl` is a method, not a variable, so you want to call it like `$this->isUrl($url)`.  Secondly you need parenthesis around your condition, so `if ($this->isUrl($url)) {`.
- `issed()` -> [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Also, you are using `isUrl()` like a test, but it does not behave like one.  It simply returns a URL, sometimes.  Your code expects it to return true/false instead.